# google cloud pub/sub -> publish on firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-pubsub

i'm currently working on with gmail api. To notify users of new mails i created a google cloud pub/sub topic.

what i'm trying to do :

1. be notified on google cloud pub / sub of new emails
2. push this notification into a endpoint
3. notify the correct user of a new email
4. local notification

I want to publish into endpoint url. The point is, google cloud pub/sub refuse to add my firebase endpoint. 
Anyone know how can i do this ?